# Writing an MCVE (minimal source code that reproduces an error) automatically?

Tags: c++, automation

When I want to ask a question on e.g. stackoverflow I usually have to post the source code.

The problem is, I am using quite a big custom framework, classes structure etc. and the problem-related parts may be localized in many places (sometimes it's very hard to detect which parts of code are important for question). I cannot post the full source code (it would be too big to read efficiently).

For that reason I usually make an effort to write an minimal code (usually in one `main.cpp` instead of tons of classes) that reproduces the problem.

I wonder - **is it possible to automate that process?**
The typical things to do here is to replace methods/functions' calls with their bodies, merge files into one `.cpp`, remove all the "not called" methods & classes, unused variables etc.

Comment: I doubt that you can automate the process of creating an MCVE using a tool.

Comment: @R Sahu I share your fears here, but I guess it's worth an asking. Anyway, thanks for the MCVE shortcut :)

Comment: Maybe it will be somebody's Master's or PhD project, if it isn't already.

Comment: I would posit that if it were "automate-able", you wouldn't need SO :)

Comment: @txtechhelp why so? If it would be "automate-able" I would only be able to post questions on SO faster. The problem would still exists and just generating the minimal source code does not answers the problem itself ;)

Comment: The vast majority of problems, once you have a little bit of programming experience, is just a case of identifying which bit of code is causing the problem (and how, which is often the trickier part). I have worked with programming for 30 odd years and I'm still finding new and interesting ways that code "isn't right", but I nearly never post on SO to find the answer - because I have learned how to solve the problems myself, and it usually doesn't take very long once you have figured out "what makes it go wrong".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real difficulty here is telling the difference between "it doesn't do what I want", "the bug went away because I removed the essential code" and the case of "it now crashes because I removed something important". And really, hitting the delete key after marking some code "don't need it" is the easy part.

Finding out what is essential to show a problem is the hard part, and it's very difficult to automate this - because it is necessary to understand the difference between what the code should do and what it actually does. Just randomly removing code will not work, because the "new" code may be broken because you removed some essential step, not because you remove unused crud - only humans [that understand the problem] can do that.

Consider this:

```
Object* something;

void Initialize()
{
    something = new Object(1, 2, 3);
}

int main()
{
   Initialize();
   // Some more code, some of which SOMETIMES sets something = NULL.
   something->doStuff();  // Will crash if object is NULL.
}
```

If we remove `Initialize`, the code will fail every time, not just every third time. But it's because the Object has not been initialized, rather than the bug in the code [which may be that we should add `if (something)` before `something->doStuff()`, or because we shouldn't set it to `NULL` in the "some more code", so "don't do that"].

When I work on a tricky problem, especially at work where we have test systems that automatically produce code for testing different functionality under different conditions, my first step is to make [or take some existing] code a "small standalone test", which is small and simple, and only does "what is necessary", rather than trying to reduce many thousands of lines of complex code that does lots of extra stuff.

For some projects, there are tools around that helps with identifying "which bit of the code is the problem", for example [`bugpoint`][1] that finds which "pass" in LLVM is guily of causing a crash.

If you have a version control system that supports this you can "bisect" code to come up with the version that introduced a particular fault [at least sometimes]. However, I had a case at work where some of my code "apparently broke things", but it turns out that some other code was "broken all the time since a long time back" because the other code was not clearing a pointer field that the API manual says should be set to `NULL`, and my code was inspecting the pointer to find out if it was pointing at the right type thing - which goes horribly wrong when the value is "whatever happens to be in that part of the stack", so it is not `NULL` and not a valid pointer. I just added the code that made this bug apparent rather than hiding itself.

[1] http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/bugpoint.html